# How to calculate risk vs payout?

Tags: probability

I am working on creating a formula for risk vs payout. The higher the risk, the more payout and vise versa. I need to factor in a edge (house edge) as well.

```
Example:
Chance to win: 50%
Edge: 1%
Bet: $1
Payout: 1.98x

Example2:
Chance to win: 20%
Edge: 1%
Bet: $1
Payout: 4.95x
```

What mathematical formula can I use to calculate this? I came up with this but it is not correct:

```
(edge / chance) * bet
```

Answer (score 0):

$\text{payout}=(1-\text{edge})\times\text{bet}\times\text{payoutMultiplier}-\text{edge}\times\text{bet}\times\text{payoutMultiplier}$ with $\text{payoutMultiplier}=0,099*\text{risk}$ and $\text{risk}=\dfrac{1}{\text{chance}}$ so 
$\text{payout}=((1-\text{edge})-\text{edge})\times\dfrac{0,099\times\text{bet}}{\text{chance}}$ which is same as

$\text{payout}=((1-\text{edge})-\text{edge})\times\dfrac{0,099\times\text{bet}}{\dfrac{1}{\text{risk}}}$